# Use XDocument as the source for XmlSerializer.Deserialize?

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml

I would like to invoke `XmlSerializer.Deserialize` passing it an `XDocument`. It can take a `Stream`, an `XmlReader` or a `TextReader`.

Can I generate one of the above from `XDocument` without actually dumping the `XDocument` into some intermediate store, such as a `MemoryStream`?

It seems that what I'm after is an implementation of `XmlReader` that works with an `XDocument`. I can't find one though.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7901558/11912

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use [`XDocument.CreateReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299560.aspx) to create an `XmlReader` that reads the contents of the `XDocument`.

Equivalently, the following will work too.

```
XmlReader GetReader(XDocument doc)
{
    return doc.Root.CreateReader();
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Here's a utility to serialize and deserialize objects to/from XDocument.

```
XDocument doc = SerializationUtil.Serialize(foo);
Foo foo = SerializationUtil.Deserialize<Foo>(doc);
```

Here's the class:

```
public static class SerializationUtil
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(XDocument doc)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var reader = doc.Root.CreateReader())
        {
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public static XDocument Serialize<T>(T value)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }

        return doc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

(Appendix to Steve Guidi's answer)

As far as I can see there is no implementation of `XmlReader` you can easily use with `XDocument` without moving the XML content through an intermediate store like a string representation of the XML and **that supports all types** that for example the `System.Xml.XmlNodeReader` supports.

The reader returned by `XDocument.CreateReader` (which is a `System.Xml.Linq.XNodeReader`, an internal class) is a `XmlReader` and works for most Xml document but not with documents that have binary data elements because its implementation [does not support Base64 or BinHex data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299560.aspx):

> Base64 and BinHex data are not supported. If you attempt to retrieve
>   these types of data (for example, by calling
>   ReadElementContentAsBase64), the reader will throw
>   NotSupportedException.

For this reader `XDocument.CreateReader().CanReadBinaryContent` is `false` in contrast to the `System.Xml.XmlNodeReader`.

For example this program throws an exception:

```
public class SomeTest
{
    public byte[] BinaryTest { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument document = new XDocument(
            new XElement("SomeTest",
                new XElement("BinaryTest", "VGVzdA==")));

        using (var reader = document.CreateReader())
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeTest));
            var someTest = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as SomeTest;
            // NotSupportedException here (as inner exception)
        }
    }
}
```

However, extracting the XML as `string` and passing it as `TextReader` into the serializer works:

```
        using (var reader = new StringReader(document.ToString()))
```

I would be interested as well if there is another way to deserialize an `XDocument` that includes binary data without converting it into a string first.

Comment: i was hoping to find a resolution for this. I have some xml content with binary data, which will make everything much slower. round tripping to a string seems insane. I think I might try and negotiate dropping the byte[] content altogether rather than take the performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I should add that after the XmlReader is created, i.e.:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
XmlReader reader = xmlDocumentToDeserialize.CreateReader();
```

then you should call:

```
reader.MoveToContent();
```

because otherwise the reader will not "point" to the first node, causing the appearance of an empty reader!  Then you can safely call Deserialize:

```
MyObject myObject = (MyObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @Simon_Weaver 's answer the best. Based on that this is my summary:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XDocSerialization
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Tests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Tests_SerializeToXDoc()
        {
            var sheep = new Animal
            {
                Name = "Sheep", Legs = 4, Nutrition = Nutrition.Herbivore
            };
            var xdoc = sheep.SerializeToXDoc();
            var ser = "<Animal " +
                      "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +
                      "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\r\n  " +
                      "<Name>Sheep</Name>\r\n  <Legs>4</Legs>\r\n  " +
                      "<Nutrition>Herbivore</Nutrition>\r\n</Animal>";

            Assert.AreEqual(xdoc.ToString(), ser);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(xdoc, typeof(XDocument));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Tests_DeserializeFromXDoc()
        {
            var Sheep = new Animal
            {
                Name = "Sheep", Legs = 4, Nutrition = Nutrition.Herbivore
            };
            var des = Sheep.SerializeToXDoc().DeserializeFromXDoc<Animal>();

            Assert.AreEqual(des.Name, Sheep.Name);
            Assert.AreEqual(des.Nutrition, Sheep.Nutrition);
            Assert.AreEqual(des.Legs, Sheep.Legs);
            Assert.AreNotSame(des, Sheep);
        }
    }

    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static T DeserializeFromXDoc<T>(this XDocument source)
        {
            if (source == null || source.Root == null)
                return default(T);

            using (var reader = source.Root.CreateReader())
                return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
        }

        public static XDocument SerializeToXDoc<T>(this T source)
        {
            if (source == null)
                return null;

            var doc = new XDocument();
            using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
                new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(writer, source);

            return doc;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Legs { get; set; }
        public Nutrition Nutrition { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Nutrition
    {
        Herbivore,
        Carnivore,
        Omnivore
    }
}
```