# How do I deserialize XML into an object using a constructor that takes an XDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(){}
}
```

I would like to be able to use an XMLSeralizer to Deserialize an XDocument directly in the constructor thus:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private XmlSerializer _s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

   public MyClass(){}
   public MyClass(XDocument xd)
   {
      this = (MyClass)_s.Deserialize(xd.CreateReader());
   }
}
```

Except I am not allowed to assign to "this" within the constructor.

Is this possible?

Comment: For what reason you want to do it like that?

Comment: Because it would be nice to instantiate the class and just feed it an XDocument and have it set itself up like that. There are other solutions but this seems most elegant to me... I am open to better suggestions.

Comment: Can't you set up the class to have data serialized into it, thus creating the instance for you?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Serializers create objects when they deserialize. You've already created an object. Instead, provide a static method to construct from an XDocument.

```
public static MyClass FromXml (XDocument xd)
{
   XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
   return (MyClass)s.Deserialize(xd.CreateReader());
}
```

Comment: and how the fridge are you supposed to do when the extraTypes (knownTypes) are not known at compile time ? This is wicked, we do not even have a pre-callback to init stuff before starting to deserialize ?

Answer (score 7):

It's more standard to use a static load method.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass Load(XDocument xDoc)
    {
        XmlSerializer _s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        return (MyClass)_s.Deserialize(xDoc.CreateReader());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Is better use some kind of factory, e.g.:

```
public static MyClass Create(XDocument xd)
{
    XmlSerializer _s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
    return (MyClass)_s.Deserialize(xd.CreateReader());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing and decided to do the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(){
   }

   public MyClass(XDocument xd)
   {
      var t = typeof(MyClass);
      var o = (MyClass)new XmlSerializer(t).Deserialize(xd.CreateReader());

      foreach (var property in t.GetProperties())
          property.SetValue(this, property.GetValue(o));
   }
}
```