# XmlReader on node without value

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I'm trying to extract data from provided [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) and add that to object using `XmlReader`, but I noticed on nodes without value, I get "\n   " instead.

**Example xml:**

```
<Items>
 <Item>
  <NodeA>Some Value</NodeA>
  <NodeB>N</NodeB>
  <NodeC />
 </Item>
 <Item>
  ...
 </Item>
</Items>
```

**Part of my modified C#:**

```
while (sub_reader.ReadToFollowing("Item"))
{
    var item = new Item();

    sub_reader.ReadToFollowing("NodeA");
    sub_reader.Read();
    item.NodeA = sub_reader.Value;

    sub_reader.ReadToFollowing("NodeB");
    sub_reader.Read();
    item.NodeB = sub_reader.Value;

    sub_reader.ReadToFollowing("NodeC");
    sub_reader.Read();
    item.NodeC = sub_reader.Value;          //This return "\n    "

    this.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Is there any function/convenient way that work the above but return null or empty string when `<NodeC />` happens? The real xml is much larger and I don't want to do if else on each of them.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Seems you already have classes correspondent to the structure of your xml. So use `XmlSerializer` for getting data from xml.

Comment: @Fabio XmlSerializer works wonder, went with this for this object since it's one of the simpler XML I got. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than calling `Read` followed by taking `Value` property, use [`ReadElementContentAsString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method:

```
sub_reader.ReadToFollowing("NodeA");
item.NodeA = sub_reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

sub_reader.ReadToFollowing("NodeB");
item.NodeB = sub_reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

sub_reader.ReadToFollowing("NodeC");
item.NodeC = sub_reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

Comment: I actually went with @Fabio comment above on using `XmlSerializer` for this problem since this is one of the simpler xml. But this is definitely the answer to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using XDocument `<NodeC/>` return `string.Empty`. Here [**dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yij6Sl)

```
     string xml = @"<Items>
<Item>
  <NodeA>Some Value</NodeA>
  <NodeB>N</NodeB>
  <NodeC />
 </Item>
 <Item>
  <NodeA>Some 2223Value</NodeA>
  <NodeB>2223N</NodeB>
  <NodeC>12344</NodeC>
 </Item>
</Items>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var result = doc.Root.Descendants("NodeC");

        foreach(var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }
```

If you want to deserialize the `XDocument` to some object you can check this answer: [How do I deserialize XML into an object using a constructor that takes an XDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901558/how-do-i-deserialize-xml-into-an-object-using-a-constructor-that-takes-an-xdocum)

```
public static MyClass FromXml (XDocument xd)
{
   XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
   return (MyClass)s.Deserialize(xd.CreateReader());
}
```

Comment: Interesting, let me play around with that. I've never used XDocument before.