# Xml Deserialization With XPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to deserialize my xml file with given parameter.

```
AddressInfo deserialized;
                XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddressInfo));
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\dataAPIv2\dataAPI\Files\sample_data.xml"))
                {
                    object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    deserialized = (AddressInfo)obj;
                }
```

I can deserialize without parameters, this works. But I want to change this operation with xpath to deserialize like process above.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/sample_data.xml"));
                XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes($"/AddressInfo/City[@code='{citycode}']"); // I want to accomplish this part."
                    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                {
                    city.city_code = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["code"].Value);
                    city.city_name = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
                    foreach (XmlNode subnode in node)
                    {
                        dist.district_name = subnode.Attributes["name"].Value;
                        dist.city_code = Convert.ToInt32(subnode.ParentNode.Attributes["code"].Value);
                        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in subnode)
                        {
                            zip.district_name = xmlNode.ParentNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
                            zip.zip_code = Convert.ToInt32(xmlNode.Attributes["code"].Value);
                            dist.Zip.Add(zip);
                            zip = new Zip();
                        }
                        city.District.Add(dist);
                        dist = new District();
                    }
                }
```

Am I able to do that?

**EDIT**
This is my AddressInfo class.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "AddressInfo")]
public class AddressInfo
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "City")]
    public List<City> City { get; set; }
    public AddressInfo()
    {
        City = new List<City>();
    }
}
```

And this is my City class.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "City")]
public class City
{
    public AddressInfo AddressInfo { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string city_name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "code")]
    public int city_code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "District")]
    public List<District> District { get; set; }
    public City()
    {
        District = new List<District>();
        
    }

}
```

I want to read cities with the given city code as a parameter. And deserialize the xml.

Comment: What do you mean with " parameters"? How does your AddressInfo look like.

Comment: have you tried xpath, mainly using XPathSelectElements ?

Comment: @Netferret it's not working with serializer

Comment: @incbeatz my bad, I can see its using XmlDocument, I have found XDocument to be more useful in these scenarios.  Its a bit old, but maybe something like this would work for you? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-use-xpath-syntax-to-select-xml-nodes-via-path-or-steps

Comment: @Netferret I can already get the values I want with xpath and xdocument but I want it be like the first code in my question with XmlSerializer and XPath combined or something like that.

Comment: As far as I understand you want to get one city be it's code from the xml document. So this would mean you just deserialice a part of the xml what is not possible. One way may be that you add a Load method to the city class see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901558/how-do-i-deserialize-xml-into-an-object-using-a-constructor-that-takes-an-xdocum
Or you deserialice the full document and the select the city from the result.

Comment: @DanielW. I can do that but my original xml file is very big and I don't want to read all the data and do linq queries after that.

Comment: If the file is large, this maybe a better option for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=net-5.0